# How can I convert a multidimension-array-string back to an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, numpy

I found an interesting problem. I am trying to save a huge list of Numpy arrays of different length to a file so I can reuse it later on. While I managed to save the list, I struggle to read it. Neither Numpy nor Python seem to be able to reconvert the string to the initial list. Any tips on how to do that?

I have already tried:
`list()`, `np.array()` and `np.fromstring()`

the list looks like that, just that it continues on about a 100000 lines

```
[[array([[[ 0.481903  ,  0.15787785,  0.05661286],
        [-0.08817253, -0.14168766, -0.13894859],
        [-0.27888685, -0.11231906,  0.26054043]],

       [[ 0.0913363 ,  0.09927119,  0.42296773],
        [ 0.45385012,  0.0164008 ,  0.823071  ],
        [-0.7438939 , -0.72650474, -0.4468163 ]],

       [[-0.34211668, -0.00215243,  0.26458675],
        [-0.23189187,  0.9370323 , -0.6188508 ],
        [-0.85894495,  0.43526295,  0.17926843]]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 0.78955674, -0.6114772 , -0.18336566],
        [-0.12059411, -1.0608526 , -0.47686368],
        [-0.00781631, -0.36990076,  0.23920381]],

       [[-0.2827969 , -0.5920803 ,  1.1788696 ],
        [-0.02591886, -0.24817304, -0.17913376],
        [-0.7543818 , -0.00784254, -0.38197488]],

       [[-0.566821  , -0.35077536,  0.32748973],
        [ 0.26770943,  0.04574856, -0.7584006 ],
        [ 1.1999835 , -0.42707324, -0.2599928 ]]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 0.501889  ,  0.11805235, -0.28508088],
        [-0.18496978, -1.2954917 ,  0.39576113],
        [ 0.03896124, -0.80981237,  0.8888588 ]],

       [[ 0.28127173, -0.04418045,  0.74862033],
        [ 0.5746676 , -1.0427617 , -0.00984947],
        [ 1.357876  ,  0.49865335, -0.5559544 ]],

       [[-0.2253674 ,  0.01848532,  0.16229743],
        [ 0.02945629, -0.3473735 , -0.16368015],
        [-0.21004315,  0.75182045, -0.14023288]]], dtype=float32),
```

`list()` and `np.array()` both work but produce totally different results from what the list initially was

EDIT: Answer found thanks to @hpaulj

The list was converted to a ndarray and then saved as a npy binary file using `np.save`

Comment: How did you save it?  While you can 'eval' a string like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, the display involving `array` is not executable.  Have you looked into `pickle`?

Comment: did it like this
fl = open(path, 'w+')
        list_stipped = str(initial_list).split()
        list_reassembled = ''
        for element in list_stipped:
            list_reassembled += element
        fl.write(list_reassembled)
        fl.close()

Haven't checked pickle yet

Comment: Anyways, doing `str(...)` on something containing `ndarray` creates a string that is not easy to recreate.  If the arrays are large enough it's impossible, because of ellipsis.  The normal ways of saving ndarray is a csv format (for 2d), `npy` and `npz` and pickle.  `h5py` can also save arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to solve the task with your help. I converted the list to a `ndarray` and then saved it with np.save as `bpy` binary file.