# Converting numpy arrays exported as text into numpy arrays again

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I copied and pasted the output of my code into a text file for later use. This output is a dictionary in which some of the values are numpy arrays but these were copied into the text file as e.g. `"key": array([0])`.
When I copy and paste back into the IPython console I get the following error: `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`.

I want to recover the entire dictionary with these numpy arrays converted back to numpy objects to keep using the data. There are several layers of dictionaries stored as values of the "parent" dictionary, many dictionaries per layer and many of these arrays in each dictionary.
Is there any way to recover this dictionary? How would you recommend I save objects for another session the next time?

Comment: "I copied and pasted the output of my code into a text file for later use." Don't do that. That isn't a reasonable thing to do. you should use one of the **many** different built-in serialization approaches. `pickle` would be the most generic way, and probably would suit your needs. I'm not sure it's even *possible* to recover your original object, since numpy sometimes will truncate output.

Comment: Similar question for a list of arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168280/how-can-i-convert-a-multidimension-array-string-back-to-an-array-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to recover the output of your previous calculation, what you could do is one of the following:

- `from numpy import array`
- do a replace all on your text file `array -> numpy.array`

Then you pass the text to `eval` (if you are doing this directly into the command line or you are copy/pasting the data from your file you can skip the eval altogheter. This is useful if you have your data stored inside a string, e.g., after reading it from the file within python)

```
from numpy import array

a="""
{
    '1':array([0]),
    '2':'some random text',
    '3':123,
    '4':{
        '4.1':array([1,2,3]),
        '4.2':{
            '4.2.1':'more nested stuff'
        }
    }
}
"""

b = eval(a)

print(b)
# {'1': array([0]), '2': 'some random text', '3': 123, '4': {'4.1': array([1, 2, 3]), '4.2': {'4.2.1': 'more nested stuff'}}}
```

As a side-note, never run eval on outputs from sources other than yourself.
This is literally executing text as python code and is obviously very vulnerable to malicious stuff.

A more secure way would be to use `ast.literal_eval` from [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). The problem being in this case that for safety reasons, it will always handle python built-ins, which does not include numpy.

Regarding other way to store your data, as suggested in the comments, [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) might do it for you

```
fname = 'output.pickle'

import pickle
# Sava data into file
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(b, f)

# Restore data from file
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    c = pickle.load(f)

print(c)

# {'1': array([0]), '2': 'some random text', '3': 123, '4': {'4.1': array([1, 2, 3]), '4.2': {'4.2.1': 'more nested stuff'}}}
```